# open a web page with batch/cmd and execute javascript

Tags: javascript, windows, batch-file, firefox, cmd

I already have a batch file containing this command:

> start firefox -new-tab www.google.de

Now I want to execute js code on this page automatically, like:

```
alert('Hello World!');
```

Just like you can do it in the js console of firefox...

I do not own the website. I want it to make it work with other websites like google.de ...

Obviously I am using firefox and windows.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use somthing like [Tampermonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/tampermonkey/) to run custom js on web page.

Comment: Thanks, works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an HTML page?

If you do, you can use the HTML to run the Javascript like this:

```
<script>
   alert('Hello World!');
</script>
```

And use the batch file to run the HTML file instead. For example, if your HTML page was in this location: `file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/page.html`, you would run the following:

```
start "" "(location of your firefox program)" "file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/page.html"
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: No, that's not what i wanted. But Thanks.